# Restlet Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK in androidstudio

Tags: android, jar, android-studio, apk, restlet

I added all the jars from restlet-android-2.3.1 archive to my libs folder in android studio. I can Make the project, but when I try to debug I'm getting this errors

```
    Path in archive: META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.converter.ConverterHelper
    Origin 1: D:\android\restlet\app\libs\org.restlet.ext.gson.jar
    Origin 2: D:\android\restlet\app\libs\org.restlet.ext.html.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.converter.ConverterHelper'
      }
    }
```

AND

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.converter.ConverterHelper
    File 1: D:\android\restlet\app\libs\org.restlet.ext.gson.jar
    File 2: D:\android\restlet\app\libs\org.restlet.ext.gson.jar
```

If, for example to:

```
  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.converter.ConverterHelper'
      }
```

then I'm getting this:

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK D:\android\restlet\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
Path in archive: META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.ClientHelper
Origin 1: D:\android\restlet\app\libs\org.restlet.ext.sip.jar
Origin 2: D:\android\restlet\app\libs\org.restlet.ext.nio.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.ClientHelper'
  }
}
```

And so on.

The classes I'm adding to exclude are base classes, and are referenced in other jars.
If to remove problematic jars from libs folder then it will work, but I ended up cutting off half of them. I'll need them. How to fix this? Are all of this restlet jars play well together?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue.  I'm just using four of the restlet jars in my project and had to put in the following to the build.gradle file. You would think there's some studio wide setting like "ignore duplicates" but I didn't find it.  I eventually added enough exclusions for it to work.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec'
}
```

Comment: In my case it was: packagingOptions {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.converter.ConverterHelper'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.ClientHelper'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.ServerHelper'
        }